# Faster or parallel loading data into single Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

Scenario:

I have about 37k items, for each of them I download some data from an external API, perform some data modification, and put into single azure block blob. Final blob ends up with around 900mb. Moreover, I'm loading data in batches so not to hit 4mb block limit. So all of the items are being processed linear, one by one.

Do you now of any way to speed up this process? I thought about loading data into blob parallel, so dividing those 37k items into 5 chunks for example and working on all of them at the same time, but from what I know, loading into a single blob at the same time from many sources is not entirely possible.

The other scenario would be creating different blobs from each of those 5 chunks, and finally combining them into one final blob. But this requires reading data from each single blob to write it into the final one - is there any way to combine blobs that consist json format faster?

Comment: What kind of blob you are trying to create - Block, Append or Page?

Comment: @GauravMantri Block blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly speed up the process by uploading chunks in parallel. Block blobs are ideal for that.

Considering you have 37k items, what you can do is upload each item as a block (i.e. essentially you will be uploading 37k blocks). You will assign each block a unique block id.

When all 37k blocks are uploaded, what you will need to do is send the list of the block ids to create the blob.

To learn more, please read the REST API documentation:

Put Block - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block

Put Block List - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list